# non-linear logistic regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, nonlinear-regression

I have the non-linear  logistic regression model
$$
\text{logit}\Pr(Y=1|X_1,X_2,)=X_1X_2\frac{1}{m(2+\theta)TD_{50}}+X_1\frac{\theta }{m(2+\theta) TD_{50}}-\frac{1}{m}
$$
which I will like to estimate $m$, $\theta$ and $TD_{50}$ in R say. Note that in a prediction setting this is just a glm. But because I will want estimates for each of the parameters, the problem becomes non-linear. Is there a simple way to fit this without writting my own estimating equations?

Comment: what do you mean by $X_i$ in the equation?

Comment: Because you can recover $m$, $\theta$, and $\operatorname{TD}_{50}$ from the three coefficients, this is nothing but a nonlinear parameterization of a perfectly linear model.  The only uncertainty concerns what you might mean by the undefined "$X_i$" on the right hand side, so please clarify that for us as @Metariat has requested.

Comment: I did clarify it, it was a typo...

Comment: I perfectly agree with you @whuber.  With some simulations I have done so far it hard to recover these parameters

Comment: "Hard" in what sense? If we write $\beta_0=-1/m,$ $\beta_1=\theta/(m(2+\theta)TD),$ and $\beta_{12}=1/(m(2+\theta)TD),$ then $\theta=\beta_1/\beta_{12},$ $TD=-\beta_0/\beta_{12}/(2+\theta),$ and $m=-1/\beta_0.$ If you are fitting the model with ML, that's all you need.  Could the problem be that you need to enforce some constraints on $m,\theta,TD$ that might be violated by applying these transformations to the MLEs of the $\beta_j$?

Comment: I require  $m,\theta,TD_{50}>0$, I think the problem had been this constrain.

Comment: Use optim with L-BFGS-B method with the constraints in place and everything works fine.

Comment: R has the package `gnm` for generalized nonlinear models